# "Whenever you draw a card" trigger w/ an empty library

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Magic: The Gathering, let's say you have out [Ormos, Archive Keeper](https://scryfall.com/card/jmp/13/ormos-archive-keeper) as well as [Psychosis Crawler](https://scryfall.com/card/c20/248/psychosis-crawler) and you're down to an empty library. Something allows you to attempt to draw a card from the empty library and you trigger Ormos's ability, but what about Psychosis Crawler? I would guess since no card is literally being drawn, Psychosis Crawler's ability wouldn't trigger, but I wonder if the act of drawing in the first place would trigger it anyways, regardless of whether a card was taken to hand from the library or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Psychosis crawler would not trigger.

This is, in part, because Psychosis Crawler has a triggered ability and Ormos, Archive Keeper's ability is a replacement effect, and one that prevents the default action of drawing a card from happening. Replacement effects like Ormos's are explained in the [Comprehensive Rules](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Replacement_effect):

> **614.1a** Effects that use the word "instead" are replacement effects. Most replacement effects use the word "instead" to indicate what events will be replaced with other events.

Because Ormos is one of the replacement effects that completely replaces the original event, it never happens, and anything that was looking for that event doesn't trigger:

> **614.6** If an event is replaced, it never happens. A modified event occurs instead, which may in turn trigger abilities. Note that the modified event may contain instructions that can’t be carried out, in which case the impossible instruction is simply ignored.

In addition to this, Psychosis Crawler isn't looking for an effect to tell you to draw a card, it's looking for the actual effect of drawing a card. If you had some effect that prevented a game loss for drawing from an empty library, like [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlatinum%20Angel%5d) you still have not drawn any cards, so the trigger conditions on Psychosis Crawler have not been met.

Think of it similarly to how [Teferi's Ageless Insight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%27s%5d%2b%5bAgeless%5d%2b%5bInsight%5d) interacts with Psychosis Crawler but in reverse. When you draw two cards you've still got a single event making you draw those cards, that event just had a replacement effect making you draw an additional card. Psychosis Crawler will trigger twice since two cards were drawn, if replacing 1 draw with 0 cards drawn still triggered Crawler once, replacing 1 card drawn with 2 would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You do not draw a card in this case so nothing happens from the [Psychosis Crawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPsychosis%20Crawler%5d) because the [Ormos, Archive Keeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOrmos%2c%20Archive%20Keeper%5d) keeps you from drawing from an empty library which would cause you to lose the game.

> If you would draw a card while your library has no cards in it, instead put five +1/+1 counters on Ormos, Archive Keeper.

If you look at what it says it is replacing the draw with something else.

If there are multiple replacement effects on the stack you chose which the order they happen according to a ruling on the

> If two or more replacement effects would apply to a card-drawing event, the player drawing the card chooses the order in which to apply them.

The rules also state that a replaced event never happens.

> 614.6. If an event is replaced, it never happens. A modified event occurs instead, which may in turn trigger abilities. Note that the modified event may contain instructions that can’t be carried out, in which case the impossible instruction is simply ignored.

Comment: I'm familiar with what the cards read, the concern I had was if the triggered abilities would see the attempt at card-drawing at the same time, then I'd have to resolve both if both would be happening or not. I suppose the replacement effect doesn't allow for Psychosis Crawler to see the card-draw attempt at all then.

Comment: @ProtoplasmicWarrior That doesn't trigger on a draw attempt, it only triggers when you actually draw a card. In this case since you can't draw a card that will never happen.

Comment: And to go further, for relevancy with Ormos's ability: It also sounds like other card-draw replacement effects wouldn't occur either, like [Thought Reflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=489745) or [Teferi's Ageless Insight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=485399)'s replacement effects with an empty library.

Comment: @ProtoplasmicWarrior If there is multiple rulings on a card you chose the order they happen. I would suggest looking at the gather page for the card as the rulings on it can be helpful.

Comment: According to the rulings on the Gatherer for Ormos, one of the rulings reads:
"If two or more replacement effects would apply to a card-drawing event, the player drawing the card chooses the order in which to apply them."

This implies that any replacement effects for card-drawing occur even if a card isn't drawn from an empty library if cards like Thought Reflection and Teferi's Ageless Insight still have triggered abilities that go off with an empty library. So all four permanents would see the attempt at card-drawing and resolve? Even if card-drawing turns into counters for Ormos?

Comment: @ProtoplasmicWarrior No, after you apply the first replacement effect, other ones are only accounted for if the event they are replacing still happens. So if you had Ormos and Thought Reflection, if you chose to apply Ormos first, then Thought Reflection wouldn't do anything because you aren't drawing a card. If you chose to apply Thought Reflection first, then Ormos would have 2 card draws to replace with counter-gaining.

Comment: 614.6 would be a good addition to this answer. "614.6. If an event is replaced, it never happens. A modified event occurs instead, which may in turn trigger abilities."

Comment: @GendoIkari I will look to add that in the morning.

Comment: @GendoIkari With Ormos, Psychosis Crawler, and Thought Reflection out and with an empty library, (forgive me for all the card-inclusions, but it's relevant for an EDH deck) you could have the triggers see a single card-draw event in the order of Thought Reflection first, then two card-draw triggers on the stack to have Psychosis Crawler see the event and resolve without taking away the draws because it doesn't say "instead," with Ormos in the end seeing the two draws turn into two triggers for itself. The "empty library" part is actually the biggest concern of this all, too.

Comment: That doesn’t work because Psychosis Crawler is a triggered ability, while the others are replacement effects. Triggered abilities only happen after the triggering event actually happens. Replacement effects do not trigger, they simply cause something to happen instead of something else. Psychosis Crawler will never trigger unless a card is actually drawn; it only cares about what happened, not what could have happened.

Comment: I think my mistake was confusing triggered abilities with replacement effects. So, replacement effects will still occur, but triggered abilities will only trigger if something is still causing them to trigger after the replacement effects resolve. If there was still a card to draw from your library, Psychosis Crawler would see it and trigger. Otherwise, the aforementioned replacement effects with an empty library take effect instead and Psychosis Crawler doesn't see any card-draws from it. Ultimately—with an empty library—Ormos's replacement effect stops Psychosis Crawler's triggered ability.

Comment: Note that even with a [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=206329) instead of any replacement effects,  with an empty library you still don't draw any cards, and no "Whenever you draw a card" effects will trigger.